# how to append data from multiple ajax requests to html table using jquery

Tags: jquery

here my code. please look once

```
var script = "";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data1) {
                    script += data.d[i].date +"--"+data.d[i].name; // here date and name is my database columns
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("Fail");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
        $("#Mytable").append(script);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Fail");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

when i run this code, i am getting error like 'Unable to get property 'date' of undefined or null reference'. can any one please help me. actually i am new to jquery.

here is my expected output

```
Date

01-01-2014 -- K N R
02-01-2014 -- ABC
03-01-2014 -- XYZ
```

Comment: please add some your JSON, seems like you are going get Date of object which has not Date type

Comment: Can you show us what is your data inside success function ? OR you can see the hierarchy of your JSON using jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: Please wait. i will show you

Comment: We need your JSON buddy, not the expected output. Without looking at your json, we wont be able to resolve it.

Comment: how can i show my json to you? actually i send request to c# and getting data.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried something like that but javascript working asynchronous. I think when you send request in loop, the loop won't wait any response and it will continue. When your requests start return any response , "i" could be reach data.d.length. So data.d[i] is null reference.

I should say again , i never tried. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (data1) {
$("#your_tr").html(data.d[i].date +'--'+data.d[i].name)
//script += data.d[i].date +"--"+data.d[i].name;
},
```